# Why is Twitter forcing to add a phone number?

Tags: twitter

I just signup for a Twitter account. I was following screen instructions. After setting username it reaches on "Add a phone number" page (see the below screenshot):[image]
I do not have any phone number and I don't want use anyone else's number. Does anyone know how to skip this step? Or any other way around?

Comment: I expect it's part of their effort to cut down on abuse and harassment. By connecting a phone to your account, you can't just simply create a new account when this one gets banned.

Comment: But in their policy they have written a phone number can be associate with 10 accounts. Only latest account will receive notifications, and for security authentication other accounts also can use same number for verification.

Comment: It was just a guess. It may even be a compromise: If you have an account that needs to be banned, then they can also ban all of the other accounts connected to that phone number.

Comment: If you uncheck "Let others find me by my phone number", does it let you proceed?

Comment: No, unchecking that doesn't work. I know some of my friends are using Twitter account without giving any phone number. Some of them have old account and some have created new one.